# oracle error while adding column to a table in database (error: 00604)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm getting this error while trying to add a new column to a table:

```
ALTER TABLE TBLCOMPANY ADD EVENTCATEGORYLEVEL NUMBER (20) DEFAULT 1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-29861: domain index is marked LOADING/FAILED/UNUSABLE
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

I have no idea why it's happening. I tried to google for it, but it seems that nobody has the answer for that. (the action that the db suggests is ridiculous).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the problem!
It's because my user hadn't privilege permission to create indexes.
I advice anyone with the same problem to run the query bellow and see if they have enough privilege to do what they're trying to:

```
select * from session_privs;
```

Comment: Finally the IT department set all the permissions to my user and it's now working fine. This way, I'll accept this as the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rebuild all indexes on `TBLCOMPANY` table.

How to find indexes:

```
select index_name from dba_indexes where table_name='TBLCOMPANY';
```

Rebuild index:

```
alter index indexname rebuild;
```

Comment: new error: Error starting at line 4 in command:
alter index companyname_index rebuild
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-29874: warning in the execution of ODCIINDEXALTER routine
ORA-29960: line 1, 
DRG-10595: ALTER INDEX COMPANYNAME_INDEX failed
DRG-50857: oracle error in drvddl.Resubmit_job
ORA-27486: insufficient privileges
29874. 00000 -  "warning in the execution of ODCIINDEXALTER routine"
*Cause:    A waring was returned from the ODCIIndexAlter routine.
*Action:   Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly
           Check the user defined warning log tables for greater details.

Comment: i'll try to find out if it has something to do with insufficient privileges

Comment: in fact.. the dba_indexes are not being generated

Comment: I found the problem! it's about the user privileges

Comment: @periback2 Congratulations! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ORA-29861: domain index is marked LOADING/FAILED/UNUSABLE
```

you have a domain (oracle text) index that corrupt or is still loading.

run this to see it/them:

```
select index_name, status from user_indexes
where index_type = 'DOMAIN' and table_name = 'TBLCOMPANY';
```

you would have to rebuild or drop the index to proceed.